# How to defeat plantera in terraria mobile

Tags: terraria-mobile

How do I beat plantera I was using full hallowed armour and a true nights edge with full gold hearts and he still killed me like nothing what do. and what do I need to defeat him?

Comment: Hallowed Armour is pretty weak by the time you get to Plantera, I'd suggest farming for Beetle or Chlorophyte Armour as your first port of call.

Comment: How do I get beetle armour?

Comment: Kill the golem. PS its harder than plantera

Comment: Can't you only get golem after killing Plantera??

Comment: Yeh you have to kill planters or you can't spawn golem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are many tips to kill Plantera. Here are some of them:**

### Wide Space

Make a wide space for you to travel. That will make Plantera not hit you that much and you can dodge him. Try going in a clockwise direction to make him go in circles.

### Artificial Jungle

You can make an artificial jungle with mud and jungle grass seeds. Plantera's Bulb may spawn in your artificial jungle. [image: Mud Blocks] [image: Jungle Grass Seeds]

### Bows

If you use a bow, you can use Chlorophyte Arrows.
They bounce off walls, and that helps to hit Plantera a few times per arrow. [image: Chlorophyte Arrows]

### Shield

A Cobalt Shield is also useful as you will not be knocked back by Plantera. [image: Cobalt Shield]

### Armour

Cholrophyte Armour is fine. Beetle Armour too. [image: Cholorophyte Armour] [image: Beetle Armour]

### Last But Not Least

A Flamethrower would be nice. It shoots a continuous stream of flame, which helps to attack Plantera. It can be easily crafted after defeating Skeleton Prime. [image: The Flamethrower]

Answer (score 1):

Turtle armor, Clockwork Assault Rifle or Megashark with explosive bullets, if you could get 2 more broken hero swords, terra blade,and a optic staff, and a big arena with no background walls so it cant grapple on to anthing. Also for accessories, have a nice pair of wings, a emblem for whatever class you are, and then whichever other accessory you fell like you need.

Answer (score -4):

Make The Arena, Using The No-Backround HOIK Mechanism Is A Idea To Keep In Mind, But No Backround Means Plantera Will Suck, And 5 Block Tall Tunnels All Around Piss The Mob Of (Metaphorically) Since Its Grapple Will Take 2-3 Minutes For It To Travel A 200x5 Tunnel, And Use Clorophyte/Shroomite Armor, I Use The Terra Blade, Light Discs, Megashark With Explosive Ammo, The Tsunami (QuadBow) With Clorophyte Arrows, Ankh Shield, The Duke Fishron Wings ( The Best Wings ) And Some 50 Holy Hand Grenades ( If Landed Right, 50 Accumulate All Of Plantera's HP, So Expensive Though, Costing 5 Gold 7 Copper And A Trip To The Nearest Water Source, Costing Around 250 Dynamites, 50 Bottle's Of Water, 2 Platinums 50 Gold Coins = Dead Plantera

Comment: Please Don't Make Every Word Begin With An Uppercase Letter (like this).  It makes readability hard.

Comment: Don't capitalize every single word, it makes reading your answer extremely difficult. And what makes you think someone will be able to beat Duke Fishron if they can't beat Plantera? Duke is usually a post-Golem boss as far as strength goes.

Comment: Oh my gosh, please put more spaces in between the items!

Answer (score -4):

I haven't defeated him yet but use the sdmg and dragon armor. You can also use the last prism

Comment: You're suggesting to use drops from a boss harder than Plantera.